# How do I load a solution namespace into a T4 tempate?

Tags: c#, t4

EDIT:

It looks like it might be due to Visual Studio running in 32bit instance and my projects being 64bit.  Is there a way around this?

Original question:

I create a T4 template class and need to load a static string from my code into it to log into a database.

This format:

```
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Configuration" #>
```

Seems to work for system namespaces but when I try with my one I get an error about it not being found.

I tried:

```
<#@ assembly name="C:\File\Path\application.exe" #>
<#@ import namespace="MyNamespace" #>
```

But I get the following Exception

> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'file:///C:\File\Path\application.exe' or one of its dependencies.

Can I load in namespaces from the code base?  If so, how?

Edit - extra info:

The entire exception message is:

> There was a problem loading the assembly
> 'C:\File\Path\application.exe' The following Exception was
> thrown:System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'C:\File\Path\application.exe' or one of its dependencies. An attempt
> was made to load a program with an incorrect format.File name:
> 'file:///C:\File\Path\application.exe'   at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
> codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
> StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
> throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
> suppressSecurityChecks)   at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
> codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
> StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
> throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
> suppressSecurityChecks)   at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
> assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
> StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
> throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
> suppressSecurityChecks)   at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String
> assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue,
> AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
> suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)   at
> System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)   at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.AttemptAssemblyLoad(String
> assemblyName)WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.To enable
> assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value
> [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.Note: There is
> some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
> logging.To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
> [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Comment: `BadImageFormatException` has a `FileName` property that'll tell you which dependency it failed to load and a `FusionLog` property containing a log path - what do these say?

Comment: They are nowhere obvious but I have added the entire exception message.  Does that help?

Comment: Is the fact that I am trying to link an exe rather than a dll causing an issue?